# Add a column in select returning whether the id from the 1st table is present inside another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I would like to select every line from one table and add a column in my select which return whether a line is present in another table with the same id.

So I would like to have everything from my table 'Yaourt' plus a column named 'Present' which will have 0 or 1 if a line in 'Sondage' is present with the IdY or not.

```
CREATE TABLE Yaourt(
    IdY    int (11) Auto_increment  NOT NULL ,
    Marque Varchar (50) NOT NULL ,
    Nom    Varchar (50) NOT NULL ,
    Type   Varchar (50) ,
    Gout   Varchar (50) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (IdY )
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Sondage(
    Est_achete Bool ,
    frequence  Int DEFAULT 0,
    Id         Int NOT NULL ,
    IdY        Int NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id ,IdY )
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

P.S. : So far I've got something like this :

```
`SELECT *,(SELECT s.IdY FROM Sondage WHERE y.IdY=s.IdY) AS "present" FROM Yaourt y;`
```

which returns something with a column named "present" but has `NULL` if it isn't present and the Id if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Sondage AS s WHERE y.IdY=s.IdY) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
   END AS "present"
FROM Yaourt y;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a LEFT JOIN. This should help:

```
SELECT y.*,
       CASE WHEN s.IdY IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS present
  FROM Yaourt y
  LEFT
  JOIN Sondage s
    ON y.IdY = s.IdY
```

Comment: I didn't know `CASE`, that will help me a lot, thank you